# Reclaim memory from Tab Bar Controller after leaving

Tags: ios, swift, memory, controller, tabs

From a Navigation Controller, my app moves to a Tab Bar Controller and then back.  The memory usage jumps 35MB with the data I have in the tab bar controller view controllers.  When moving back from the Tab Bar Controller, I'd like to reclaim that memory.  Can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

It is done automatically untill there is a memory leak. Check if tab bar controller is dellocated when moving back.